# How to print all the array elements in a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

I have an array which I want to print on a JOptionPane to get a result like this:

[image]

with the array being the book list. I don't know how to

Following is the code for the array:

```
String[] booksOfSubGenre = new String[bookInfo.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < bookInfo.size(); i++) {
            int j = 0;
            if (bookInfo.get(i).getSubGenre().equals(selectedSubGenreInCombobox)) {
                subGenreCount++;
                System.out.println(subGenreCount);
                booksOfSubGenre[j] = bookInfo.get(i).getBookName();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display in that format, you can use String.format() to create a string template and pass in the data.

```
String text = String.format("There are %o books of Sub-Genre Fantasy: %s", subGenreCount , bookInfo.get(i).getBookName());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text, "Query Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

To display multiple books, you can append the book names together and display it as one string.

```
    String appendedText = "";
    int subGenreCount = 0;
    String[] booksOfSubGenre = new String[bookInfo.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bookInfo.size(); i++) {
        int j = 0;
        if (bookInfo.get(i).getSubGenre().equals(selectedSubGenreInCombobox)) {
            subGenreCount++;
            System.out.println(subGenreCount);
            booksOfSubGenre[j] = bookInfo.get(i).getBookName();
            appendedText += bookInfo.get(i).getBookName() + "\n";
        }
    }
    String text = String.format("There are %o books of Sub-Genre Fantasy: %s", subGenreCount , appendedText);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text, "Query Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Does this solution only display one book at a time, or is it designed to display 2 books as the message implies? I tried the code but could not get the format to recognize the array and display all values in the array in a single option pane.

Comment: This code is for displaying one book at a time. If you want to display multiple books you need to append the text. When I'm free I will provide you with the answer for displaying multiple books.

Comment: *I will provide you with the answer for displaying multiple books* - I know how to display multiple books as I demonstrated in my answer. What I don't understand is why the OP wants a solution to display 1 book at a time. As a user I would be annoyed at having to click on the Ok button 10 times if there are 10 books to display. Not a very friendly interface.

Answer (score 1):

Format your text output using HTML.

So your text string might look like:

```
String text = "<html>There are two books of Sub-Genre Fantasy:<br>The Lost Hero<br>Another Book>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the second parameter, named *message*, in all the [showMessageDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-) methods of class `javax.swing.JOptionPane` is `Object` which means it can be *any* class, including *Swing* components like `javax.swing.JList`.

Consider the following.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class OptsList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] booksOfSubGenre = new String[]{"The Lost Hero",
                                                "The Hobbit",
                                                "A Game of Thrones"};
        int count = booksOfSubGenre.length;
        String subgenre = "Fantasy";
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        String text = String.format("There are %d books of Sub-Genre %s", count, subgenre);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JList<String> list = new JList<>(booksOfSubGenre);
        panel.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Query Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following:

[image: running app]